# How do I stop a score at a certain number on p5js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I can't get the score to stop at 10 no matter what I try. I tried looking at previous posts from this site and i've tried them and they don't work. I tried using a conditional, and putting (score >= 10) and other things but it won't work. I looked at a previous post that tried to explain how to do it but it does the same thing as the code I have currently does. Could I get some help?

```
  /* VARIABLES */
  let catcher, fallingObject;
  let score = 0;
  let stickFigureVisble = true;
  let catcherImg;

  /* PRELOAD LOADS FILES */
  function preload(){
  catcherImg=loadImage("assets/stickFigure.png");

   }

  /* SETUP RUNS ONCE */
  function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400);



  //Create catcher 
  catcher = new Sprite(catcherImg, 200,380,100,20, "k");
  catcher.color = color(95,158,160);
  catcherImg.resize(50,50);

  //Create falling object
  fallingObject = new Sprite(100,0,10);
  fallingObject.color = color(0,128,128);
  fallingObject.vel.y = 2;
 }

/* DRAW LOOP REPEATS */
function draw() {
background(224,224,224);  



   // Draw directions to screen
  fill(0);
  textSize(12);
  text("Move the \ncatcher with the \nleft and right narrow 
  keys to \ncatch the falling \nobjects. Reach \n10 points to 
  win \nthe game." , width-100, 20);

   //If fallingObject reaches bottom, move back to random 
    position at top
  if (fallingObject.y >= height) {
  fallingObject.y = 0;
  fallingObject.x = random(width);
  fallingObject.vel.y = random(1,5);

    }
  // Moving catcher
 if (kb.pressing("left")) {
 catcher.vel.x = -3;
 } else if (kb.pressing("right")) {
  catcher.vel.x = 3;
 } else {
  catcher.vel.x = 0;
   }
 // Stop catcher at edges of screen
  if (catcher.x < 30) {
  catcher.x = 30;
  } else if (catcher.x > 370) {
  catcher.x = 370;
  } 
 // If fallingObject collides w catcher, move back to random 
 position at top
  if (fallingObject.collides(catcher)) {
  fallingObject.y = 0;
  fallingObject.x = random(width);
  fallingObject.vel.y = random(1,5);
  fallingObject.direction = "down";
  score = score + 1;

 }
  // Score keeper
 fill(0);
 textSize(17);
 text("Score: " + score, width-390, 35);
 if (score === 10) {
  return true;
 } else if (score =< 10) {
  return false;
  }

 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more relevant code to make this a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As is, this is just a partial script and we can't see the full context of what `Score keeper` is or how score gets updated, etc. All we can see is that in a conditional somewhere you're updating `score += 1` and down in the Score keeper you're returning a bool whether score is 10 or not. When incrementing the score, there's no upper bound (you're blindly adding 1 each time), so maybe you want your conditional to be `if (score >= 10)` instead?

Comment: thank u so much i tried that but can i just update this post and youll see it?

Comment: @red yes, click [edit] and add all the necessary in order to create a [mcve]. Please read [ask].

Comment: alright, all fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The `draw()` function won't stop after returning a value. You will have to make it stop manual by using `noLoop()` function or making your own way of checking the state of the game.

Try replacing `return true;` with `noLoop()`.